# Are Android gradle tasks open sourced?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I use `./gradlew connectedAndroidtest` to test my android app.

When the connectedAndroidtest task running, from the terminal, I can get the task that ran many sub-tasks.

```
:assembleDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:connectedDebugAndroidTest ...
```

but I don't understand the sub-tasks details.

I try to find gradle source code but can't find any about `connectedDebugAndroidTest` tasks.

Are android tasks open source? Or where I can know more details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to see Android Build Tools source code, there is open Google repository with it: [android/platform/tools/build/master](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master)

Specifically Android Gradle Plugin: [build/gradle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/).

If you would like to see manual for specific task, you could execute:

```
./gradlew help --task "${taskName}"
```

In your case it should be:

```
./gradlew help --task connectedAndroidTest
```

Output:

```
Detailed task information for connectedAndroidTest

Path
     :app:connectedAndroidTest

Type
     Task (org.gradle.api.Task)

Description
     Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.

Group
     verification
```